# While sorting a collection or any data set, How does reverse ordering works in Java 8?

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8

I am learning Java 8 from examples/questions on stackoverflow while solving some algorithm questions. I have query: When using Comparator.reverseOrder() or reversed(), whether JVM understands that I want reverse order hence it applies logic in such a way that while sorting itself the order is maintained in descending fashion . Or one more pass (O(n)) is taken by JVM to change a ascending ordered datastructure to descending order datastructure.

```
int[][] arr= new int[][]{{1,4},{3,5}};
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(a -> a[0]).reversed());
```

Another example for a Map, I perform some operations on the map trackW which i haven't copied here.

```
Map<String,Integer> hmsort= new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String,Integer> trackW = new HashMap<>();

trackW.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String,Integer>comparingByValue().
                    thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder())))
            .forEachOrdered(x->hmsort.put(x.getKey(),x.getValue()));
```

Also If someone can fix/suggest better option for sorting hashmap in this way (ascending based on value and then descending based on key) I would be really glad.

Regards.

Comment: You can read [the source code yourself](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l5167); additionally, you can generally presume that the developers of a system of the quality of OpenJDK will take an obvious improved approach instead of doing something excessively inefficiently.

Comment: Thanks.I will take a look at the code. Yes that was my assumption but just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using Comparator.reverseOrder() or reversed(), whether JVM understands that I want reverse order hence it applies logic in such a way that while sorting itself the order is maintained in descending fashion .

Yes. The Comparator itself is reversed. It is not the collection that is sorted first and then reversed.

The "logic" inside of that comparator is not visible to the calling code (let alone "the JVM"), the sorting algorithm just calls into the comparator (for two values at a time) and looks at the results. As such, the calling code (such as `Arrays.sort`) has no understanding if the comparator is the "normal" one or a reversed version.